# iOS Swift 3 BLE CBCharacteristic / Size 8 Bytes (4 Words) / How to separate the words

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to read out data from a Bluetooth Module. 
There is a characteristic with 4 values, stored in 8 bytes/4 words.

Here is the data, that is stored in characteristic.value:

```
0x01 0x01 0x00 0x01 0x04 0x05 0x00 0x01
```

I work with Swift 3.

Here´s the code

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

 let data = characteristic.value
 let dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
 print("Data: \(String(describing: dataString))")
}
```

The "print" function shows the following result in the output Window:

```
datastring: Optional("\u{01}\u{01}\0\u{01}\u{04}\u{05}\0\u{01}")
```

I stuck in separating the CBCharacteristic content (8 Bytes shown above) into 4 separate values (each value should consist of 1 word).

I´d like to have that result:

```
Value 1: 0x01 0x01
Value 2: 0x00 0x01
Value 3: 0x04 0x05
Value 4: 0x00 0x01
```

Each 2 Bytes should be one value.
Could you please help me to separate those value and to convert that words into integers?

Thank you very much.

Very best regards
Bursche

Comment: Hint: use the `bytes` or `getBytes` methods on the data.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code for get integer value from 2 bytes.
LSB(little endian)

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

   let value = [UInt8](characteristic.value!)
   let newValue = ((Int16(value[1]) << 8) | (Int16(value[0])))
   let intValue = Int(newValue)
   print(intValue)
}
```